# Integral $\int_0^b \frac{1-\exp\{-x\}}{x}\text{d}x\qquad 0<b<\infty$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

Is there any closed form expression for the definite integral
$$\int_0^b \frac{1-\exp\{-x\}}{x}\text{d}x\qquad 0<b<\infty$$
as I could not find one in [Gradshteyn and Ryzhik Table of Integrals](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lepp.cornell.edu%2F~ib38%2Ftmp%2Freading%2FTable_of_Integrals_Series_and_Products_Tablicy_Integralov_Summ_Rjadov_I_Proizvedennij_Engl._2.pdf&ei=G4W3VNTAF4LpapX_gYgO&usg=AFQjCNF2feiY7EG2E53yAnrkx-tPeTdM9A&sig2=zxDQGrrq5J5Rf4Cjpof97w&bvm=bv.83640239,d.d2s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning the antiderivative $$\int\frac{e^{x}}{x}dx=\text{Ei}(x)$$ where appears   the exponential integral function which would present problems around $x=0$. But, provided $b>0$  $$\int_0^b \frac{1-e^ {-x}}{x}dx=\gamma+\log (b)+\Gamma (0,b)$$

Comment: Thank you. I had also found this formula on a website, as well as the series expansion $$- \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-z)^k}{k\,(k!)}$$ by a simple integration. I was wondering if there was something more "explicit" but apparently not.

Comment: Bonjour ! This just implies the definition of  the exponential integral function. In thatsense, it is explicit. Cheers :-)

Comment: Merci, implicit vs. explicit is in the beholder's eye!

Comment: Well, we could start here a long philosophical discussion ! Is $\sin(x)$ explicit ? Là est la question. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

This integral is known as the the complementary exponential integral $\mathrm{Ein}(b)$. It is entire, see http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2.E3 for the definition and http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.6.E4 for the power series.